# Div element not hiding even after hiding the tooltip in highcharts

Tags: html, highcharts, tooltip

I basically want to hide the tooltip on click anywhere in the chart. For this I have configured tooltip as follows:

```
 tooltip:{
           hideDelay: 50000 //So that the tooltip stays open for a long time
 }
```

You can check out the example at:

http://jsfiddle.net/e56KT/16/

Anyone with bright ideas!!!

Updated Question:

Before hiding the tooltip:

[image: Before hiding the tooltip:]

After hiding the tooltip:

[image: After hiding the tooltip:]

As you can see the div element si not hiding even after hiding the tooltip by the method you described. In a series chart, if we customize the tooltip with increased width and height, the mouse over on other markers doesn't work as this div element stays on top of those markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually working.  It appears not to though because the `hide` method honors the `hideDelay`.  If you want it to hide immediately try:

```
hideTooltip = function(){
    chart.tooltip.label.fadeOut();
    chart.tooltip.isHidden = true;
}
```

This is what the `hide` method does internally.

Finally, if you want it to hide if you click anywhere on the chart then I'd hook both the `chart: events: click` event and the `plotOptions: events: click` event.

See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e56KT/17/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Infact today I also figured out the same answer. Now I am facing a new challenge. When I hide the tooltip, the container stays alive in the chart but in invisible mode. As a result of which I am not able to launch the tooltip, when I mouse over the markers which fall under the region of previously opened tooltip. Note: I expanded the tooltip size to 200 x 300.

Comment: @user3282870, I don't understand your new challenge.  My fiddle/code above opens the tooltip back up if you re-mouse over the marker where you just closed it.

Comment: To reproduce my issue, firstly increase the height and width of the tooltip [<div height=300 width=300> </div>]

Comment: To reproduce my issue, firstly increase the height and width of the tooltip [<div height=300 width=300> </div>].  My concept is to first return a <div> element in formatter of tooltip and then using setTimeout() create a chart to render to that <div>. By doing this i would  be able to display a chart inside the tooltip. Now after using your code to hide [IN CHROME], although the chart and <div> element do get hidden, but if you inspect the area using CHROME console [activated by pressing shift + I], I div element still stays present.

Comment: I have updated my question with soem  screenshots to give you a clear picture of the issue.

Comment: @user3282870, update the fiddle to demonstrate your problem...  I've tried and still don't see an issue: http://jsfiddle.net/e56KT/18/

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle link that you provided. Steps to reproduce: 1. Mouse over any bar. 2. After that mouse over near the label 635. 3. This time tooltip will hide. 4. Repeat the steps 1-2. 5. This time tooltip won't appear if you mouse over near the 635 label bar region. Reason: The div element is not hidden on label.fadeout() or label.hide().  Use inspect element of chrome to see the div element's existence